# Why do you need "? extends" in generics

Tags: java, generics

Does anyone have a good explanation why the `? extends` syntax has to be used in generics?  I know what the syntax enforces but it just doesn't seem to be consistent with how non-generic type checking is done in Java.  For example:

```
void someMethod() {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    doSomethingWithStrings(strings);
    doSomethingWithObjects(strings); // << This doesn't compile
}

void doSomethingWithStrings(Collection<String> strings) {}

void doSomethingWithObjects(Collection<Object> objects) {}
```

That will have compile errors where commented, while in this next example there are obviously no compile errors:

```
void someOtherMethod() {
    String string = "worksInBothPlaces";
    doSomethingWithAString(string);
    doSomethingWithAObject(string);
}

void doSomethingWithAString(String string) {}

void doSomethingWithAObject(Object object) {}
```

I know the first block can be fixed by changing the second signature to

```
void doSomethingWithObjects(Collection<? extends Object> objects) {}
```

but again that doesn't seem consistent with out type checking is done elsewhere.  Is there some clear example where without `? extends` some generic class would be harder or even impossible to write.

Comment: For similar questions/answers, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+covariance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the generic can't confirm reallocation stuff.

```
void AddSomething(Collection<Stuff> object)
{
  object.Add(new Stuff());
}
```

will fail if you try to call

```
AddSomething(new Collection<ChildStuff>())
```

because you can't add a Stuff to a ChildStuff collection.

For the compiler/runtime/whatever to know that your function won't do anything like that, it needs to be told that it's okay to accept subtypes, and that's done through the `? extends` syntax.

Comment: Ah, well that makes perfect sense to me.  I knew there would be some simple example I wasnt thinking of.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, because a `Collection<String>` is not the same type as a `Collection<Object>` and it is not a subtype of it either.

That is `Collection<String>` **is not** a `Collection<Object>`, where as `String` **is** a `Object`.

The detail as to why this is so is quite complicated, and you would be best served by referring to [Angelika Langer's](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) FAQ on generics in Java.